# This expression is not constructable. Type 'typeof import("jspdf")' has no construct signatures

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, nuxt.js, jspdf

I am using **jsPDF** v1.5.3

I have **imported** it like this

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'
```

and in **method** I have this

```
 var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [175, 91])
```

**But** I have **type** error here

[image]

and also I have declared **@types/jspdf** module like this

```
    declare module 'jspdf'{
 
}
```

how can I **fix** this ??

Answer (score 2):

This wildcard import is not needed:

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'
```

You can just use a named import:

```
import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf'
```

If you want the wildcard import anyways, you have to use:

```
new jsPDF.jsPDF(...)
```

which is redundant